# formatting table/matrix in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use a package where the table they've used is in a certain format, I am very new to R and don't know how to get my data in this same format to be able to use the package.
Their table looks like this:

```
     Recipient
Actor  1 10 11 12  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
   1   0  0  0  1  3  1  1  2  3  0  2  6
   10  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   11 13  5  0  5  3  8  0  1  3  2  2  9
   12  0  0  2  0  1  1  1  3  1  1  3  0
   2   0  0  2  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  2  1
   3   9  9  0  5 16  0  2  8 21 45 13  6
   4  21 28 64 22 40 79  0 16 53 76 43 38
   5   2  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  3  0  0  1
   6  11 22  4 21 13  9  2  3  0  4 39  8
   7   5 32 11  9 16  1  0  4 33  0 17 22
   8   4  0  2  0  1 11  0  0  0  1  0  1
   9   0  0  3  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Where mine at the moment is:

```
  X0 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
0  0  2  3  3  0  0
1  1  0  4  2  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  2  2  0  1  0
4  0  0  3  2  0  2
5  0  0  3  3  1  0
```

I would like to add the recipient and actor to mine, as well as change to row and column names to 1, ..., 6.

Also my data is listed under Data in my Workspace and it says:

```
'num' [1:6,1:6] 0 1 ...
```

Whereas the example data in the workspace is shown in Values as:

```
'table' num [1:12,1:12] 0 1 13 ...
```

Please let me know if you have suggestion to get my data in the same type and style as theirs, all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `'num' [1:6,1:6]` means your data set is a matrix, try `is.matrix()` or `class()` on it to see it. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`. (`data` is the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you have a matrix like so:

```
m <- matrix(c(1:9), 3)
rownames(m) <- 0:2
colnames(m) <- paste0("X", 0:2)
#  X0 X1 X2
#0  1  4  7
#1  2  5  8
#2  3  6  9
```

First you need to remove the Xs and turn it into a table:

```
colnames(m) <- sub("X", "", colnames(m))
m <- as.table(m)
#  0 1 2
#0 1 4 7
#1 2 5 8
#2 3 6 9
```

Then you can set the dimension names:

```
names(dimnames(m)) <- c("Actor", "Recipient")
#     Recipient
#Actor 0 1 2
#    0 1 4 7
#    1 2 5 8
#    2 3 6 9
```

However, usually you would create the contingency table from raw data using the `table` function, which would automatically return a table object. So, maybe you should fix the step creating your matrix?